# oracle creating table from another table created partially ; unable to extend temp space

Tags: sql, oracle

We are trying to create a table from another table with method -

`create table tab1 as select * from tab2;`

But the process failed with error

> ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by 8192 in tablespace

However the table `tab1` is created with partial data only. There is a count mismatch in tab1 and `tab2`. Any of these two tables being not populated/ updated by any transaction. This happened with a couple of tables.

What my knowledge says about it, a create table should create a table at all or not at all. There is no possibility of table being created partially.

Any insight is suggested from experts.

Comment: Still looking for an expert comment.

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following to determine the filename for the existing tablespace as sysadmin

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_DATA_FILES;
```

Then extend the size of the datafile as follows (replace the filename with the one from the previous query):

```
ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLEXE\ORADATA\XE\SYSTEM.DBF' RESIZE 4096M;
```

You can first try below command or ask DBA to give the privilege:

```
 grant unlimited tablespace to <schema_name>;
```

Comment: The error messages refers to the TEMP tablespace - those are resized differently (and please do not use SYSTEM as an example - that tablespace should be left alone)

Comment: Thank you for the work around of tablespace issue. But that was not the question here. I am worried about how table got created partially.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the cause of the error aside (addressed by @[Leo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6664990/leo) in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155443/5853770)):

I have not found anything specific on transactions for `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT`. Any `CREATE TABLE` statement is a DDL operation, which in turn are generally non-transactional operations.

This is just a speculation, but I'd say that the table creation did succeed. The instruction you gave is basically a two in one, where the first one is the actual table creation, which does work (and as it is not transactional, it can't be affected by the second one) and the second is a variant of a bulk insert from select (with implicit commits for batches), which breaks at some point.

This is probably not answering your question, but as the operation is apparently two-phase anyway, if you need more transactional approach, you would benefit from splitting the operation into two separate ones:

first:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 AS SELECT * FROM tab2 WHERE 1 = 2;
```

second:

```
INSERT INTO tab1 SELECT * FROM tab2;
```

This way if the second part fails, you will not end up with a partial insert. You will still have the table in place though.

Comment: I often uses the approach suggested by you of creating an empty table first and then populate it using source table. But I am not going to use it here, because these are huge tables I am working on.                                     
However my question remains unanswered here how the table got created partially.